# Downsample numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two numpy arrays. One has features and the other the corresponding labels.

There are 3 classes, but the dataset is imbalanced, so I would like to balance it out by  downsample one class. It has like 10k elements, I would like to have it around 2k like the other classes. I tried to do it with a for loop by creating a new array but I am sure there is a more clean method for that.

In the end there should be the two numpy arrays, one with the features but with the elements removed that also got removed in the labels array based on the class.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `indices = np.random.randint(0, len(elements), 2000)`, to get 2000 random indices that you want to take from the original array, then you can use `data[indices]` to get the required 2000 elements.

Comment: but that would give me not necessarily the elements I want to downsample from the specific class right?

Comment: There is no code example, so I am not sure if I understand the question correctly. But the code I propose creates a mask of 2,000 indices that you can use to create a smaller dataset out of the big dataset of 10,000 elements. Using `data[indices]` will result in a downsampled dataset.